# Force Specific Response Header for JSF webapplication on Glassfish

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, http-headers

We have a Java EE 6 web application with JSF 2.0 running on Glassfish 3.1.

There we encountered a strange bug: the Mime type of the response header send by Glassfish to the client depends on the order of the allowed Mime types in the request header send by the Browser. So in some cases (depending on the browser), the Mime type of the response is wrong, resulting in a broken html page.
But it would take pretty long to explain that thing. So to workaround this problem we now want to do just one thing:

Force the response header type for the whole web-application to "text/html".

Currently, we do that with a Servlet Filter configured in the Web.xml:

```
@WebFilter("/BaseFilter")
public class BaseFilter implements Filter {
     public BaseFilter() {
     }

     public void destroy() {
     }

     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                          FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
     }

     public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
     }
 }
```

configuration in web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>BaseFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.company.web.filter.BaseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>BaseFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  <!-- these patterns should match cached resources -->
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

So my question is, is there a better way to enforce a specific response header, especially by just configuring it instead of implementing a ServletFilter?

Is there a Glassfish option to do that?

Comment: What is been returned instead? Facelets defaults to `text/html`, only the charset may vary depending on server/client details. As to the filter approach, you don't want to send JS/CSS/image files with that content type. Rather map on `<servlet-name>` of JSF servlet instead of `<url-pattern>` of `/*`.

Comment: "Facelets defaults to text/html, only the charset may vary depending on server/client details" No. In our application, the response header varies, depending on the order of the allowed Mime types in the request header. It looks different (is borken or not), depending on the browser (either its text/html or its application/xhtml, which breaks the rendering). So we want to enforce it to text/html. Thanks for the hint regarding JS/CSS, we'll change that to filter only the JSF Servlet.

Comment: Hmm, sounds more like the browser's fault that it is telling that it prefers `application/xhtml` but can't render it properly.

Comment: No, I don't think it's a Browser problem. If we serve the exact HTML output of JSF with an Apache, it's rendered correctly by all  Browsers, no matter in which order their allowed Mime-Types are.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it in the default template by the `contentType` attribute of the `<f:view>`.

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
```